# Is it possible to display pdf in Android WebView by using pdf.js?

Tags: android, pdf, android-webview, pdf.js

Would it be possible to use [pdf.js](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js) to display a PDF file in Android WebView?

I know the common solution is to use google doc or launch an intent. However, I wish to open it in my app anyway.

It seems that [pdf.js](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js) provide a pretty good solution to display pdf in browser. I want to know if I can do the same on Android. 
I want to download the pdf file to a temporary place first, and then display it in WebView.

Comment: Can you please share your findings ? Which route did you go ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, if you can render something in your browser, in this case a [`webkit`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebKit) based browser. you can do it in your webview too but will take much time than your desktop browser.

There is [new api for PDF](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/pdf/package-summary.html) in Kit-Kat, am not sure if it can render a PDF file.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. here is one thing you may need to pay attention -- **protocol choice and a http server**

You can use "file://" or "http:" as the url protocol to let webkit to load the viewer.html.

If you use "file:///", you may find the cross domain issue. (error message looks like "XMLHttpRequest cannot load file://mnt/sdcard/somewhere/cache/web/locale/locale.properties. Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP."), and there will be the similar problem if you put the pdf files in some other places.

The resolution to this issue may be to revise the viewer.html to convert it as a single file.

If you use "http:" as the protocol, you may need a small http server in you Android device.

Good Luck